# What is "name=" for in Google App Engine Data Store Key Field

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

The User class is defined as below

```
 @PersistenceCapable(detachable="true")
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent
    private String email;

    @Persistent
    private String firstname;

    @Persistent
    private String lastname;
```

In PROD, I added a user with email="david12@gmail.com", firstname=something, lastname=something via JDO. Then in Datastore Viewer, **the ID/Name field has a value of "Name=david12@gmail.com"**. **Why was "Name=" added?** My program cannot find user with key = "david12@gmail.com". It can in my DEV PC though where there is never "Name=".

**[Added source code of retrieving a User instance]** It works well in my DEV PC.

```
    public static User getUser(String email){
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    User user, detached = null;
    try {
        user = pm.getObjectById(User.class,
            email);

        // If you're using transactions, you can call
        // pm.setDetachAllOnCommit(true) before committing to automatically
        // detach all objects without calls to detachCopy or detachCopyAll.
        detached = pm.detachCopy(user);
    } 
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        pm.close();
    }
    return detached;
}
```

[image]

![enter image description here][2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the id can be either an auto-generated number or a custom string, "name=" is there to make it clear the id is a string (otherwise you would get a "id=").

As for not finding the user, the problem must be in how the query is made, so we would need more insight into your code to figure it out.

Comment: A piece of code is added to show the query. Note the whole application works well in my DEV PC.

Comment: I presume you're sure the email you're looking for is the right one, by debugging the production app running? This simple errors are the hardest to catch right :/